# Good practice to resize a PNG aiming to act as smartphones' SplashScreen

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, png, resize

I own a PNG (640x1136), that I want to resize in order to fit all the smartphone screens.

I have Photoshop and illustrator.

I opened Photoshop, right-clicked on the PNG, and select "Edit Contents", that opens Illustrator.

However, the work space (in Illustrator) is totally blank, no trace of my SplashScreen model.
Probably due to a wrong selection when Illustrator suggests me to convert the colors..when importing in Illustrator.

What are the steps to achieve the case of resizing, without losing quality?

Comment: What does " I want to resize in order to fit all the smartphone screens" mean? Is there a special size you mean? Or do you want to resize the image? PNG is a bitmap format, Illustrator creates vector graphics ...

Comment: I imagine that I might blend some notions. I'm very new to Adobe softwares. I just want to optimally resize the image regarding the nature of the device (iPhone, Ipad etc.). So you mean that PNG does not make sense with Illustrator due to the nature of the structure? (vectors vs bitmap)

Comment: At last it depends on the image. Illustrator uses vector praphics to be able to be resizable without quality changes. There are a few images that can be vectorised, logos for example. All other not. So use Photoshop for bitmaps, use illustrator for vector graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can ask your PC/Mac to open the file in Photoshop instead of Illustrator, since it is much simpler to manipulate the change in size.

Once opened in PS, and select the option below:

[image: Image Size Option]

A pop up box will appear to show:
[image: Change the size]

Then simply change the values to either the percent option, or click the dropdown and choose pixels. Put in your values and click ok!

Done!

Comment: Nice :) But what about quality loss if I want to make the image larger. Is the "Resample" command useful for this?

Comment: I just tested a few times, and the quality loss is minimal. I changed the screen in the example from 800x700px, to 8000x7000px without losing much.